# Undefined variable: my_query + Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a child theme job board theme which was last updated Oct 30, 2016, so I am having some issues with it, it is not being updated by the person who made it, so any help will be appreciated as I am not a developer. Maybe you can see a way to fix it:

> Undefined variable: my_query in /wp-content/themes/theme-name/loop-job-home.php on line 54

> Notice: Trying to get property 'post' of non-object in /wp-content/themes/theme-name/loop-job-home.php on line 54

> Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /wp-content/themes/theme-name/loop-job-home.php on line 54

I searched and on many websites they suggest I should define my_query as `$my_query = new WP_Query($args);` , after I did that from https://suttonedfoundation.org/uk/646575-wordpress-loop-only-unique-values-for-meta_key-php-mysql-arrays-wordpress.html, now I am getting only the error

> Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /wp-content/themes/theme-name/loop-job-home.php on line 54

So was it correct to define it like that and how to fix "Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in"
from loop-job-home.php:

```
<?php appthemes_before_post( APP_POST_TYPE ); ?>
 38 
 39             <?php
 40                                 global $featured_job_cat_id;
 41 
 42                                 $post_class = array('job');
 43                                 $expired = jr_check_expired($post);
 44 
 45                                 if ($expired) {
 46                                         $post_class[] = 'job-expired';
 47                                         $action = get_option('jr_expired_action');
 48                                         if ($action=='hide') :
 49                                                 continue;
 50                                         endif;
 51                                 }
 52                                 $alt=$alt*-1;
 53 if ($alt==1) $post_class[] = 'job-alt';
 54         if ( is_object_in_term( $my_query->post->ID, 'job_cat', array($featured_job_cat_id) ) ) $post_class[] = '';
 55 
 56 
 57             ?>
```

Comment: It's telling you `$my_query->post` is not an object. Dump the value of `$my_query` and see what it contains.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, I will try to do that, but I am not a developer so I have to search for how to do that.

Comment: Here's a guide to the [basics of debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/).

Comment: This will take more time then I thought. This was a child theme, I think I have to use the main theme instead as it is still being updated, thank you for the effort.